# Laravel eloquent where clause issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following structure of the table:

```
`id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`order` int(11) NOT NULL,
`category` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

I have five confirm records in table where i am querying table like this :

`$recommended = App\Recommend::where('category', '=', 'editorpicks');`

But the result comes empty, Let me paste the column name and value against it straight from DB.

column name : `category`

value : `editorpicks`.

Why its not working.

I have tried it in `tinker` also.

Comment: have you checked case sensitivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
App\Recommend::where('category', 'editorpicks')->get();
```

Note, you don't need to use "=" in where, if no conditional is provided, the `where` clause will default to `equals`. `get()` grabs the collection. You could also do `first()` to grab first single record, `last()`, `find($id)`, etc.

It's also good practice to namespace the model as well. So add `use App\Recommend` to top of controller (I'll assume this already makes sense) and then just use `$recommended = Recommend::where(...`. Keep things clean.